# Google Charts C# API Overlapping Bar Chart

Tags: c#, bar-chart, google-visualization

Hi I'm trying to leverage the C# GCharts API however absolutely need 'overlapping' not 'stacked' bar chart functionality. Is there a way to acheive this throuhg the API .. I'm looking into some jQuery plugins which seem to have some overlapping ability.. but would much prefer to use the wrapper.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by graphing the difference between my data points to give the appearance of overlapping. When doing this remember to apply a custom tooltip so that the mouseover displays the correct value.

Comment: Thanks i ended up using MSCharts. Was very easy to use and pretty robust to boot.